# Xamarin.Android F# template fails to build on VS2017 15.7.1

Tags: f#, xamarin.android

I have Visual Studio 2017 Version 15.7.1 + Xamarin.Android 8.3.0.19 running on Win7. When I create an F# project based on Blank App Android template, build fails with the following error:

> 1>FSC: error FS0193: Could not find file
>   'C:\Users\vhrd47\source\repos\App5\App5\ProvidedTypese4595d25-58bd-4f87-96fc-ec2d29402d62.dll'.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: It seems to be a bug. https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/4795 You may need to downgrade to 15.6.7 fixes the problem.

Comment: Indeed it was. Thank you Billy. It is fixed in 15.7.2 which is now released.